# how to understand double pointers in a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, double-pointer

i found a useful page which explained [how to use double pointers in a linked list](http://www.mvps.org/user32/linkedlist.html).

But there are a few points that i could not understand.

```
void AddNodeSorted(node* pNewNode)
{
  node** ppScan = &pRootNode;
  while(*ppScan != NULL && compare(*ppScan,pNewNode))
    ppScan = &(*ppScan)->pNext;

  pNewNode->pNext = *ppScan;
  *ppScan = pNewNode;
}
```

In this function, I could not understand how the last two lines work. In my point of view, after the `while loop`, the new item needs to insert before the element which `ppScan` indirectly points to.

So `pNewNode->pNext = *ppScan` works alright. Then what's the meaning of `*ppScan = pNewNode` ? `pNewNode->next = pNewNode`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since "ppScan = &(*ppScan)->pNext;","*ppScan = pNewNode;" will let the last element to point to the new node.